# Flex box mis alignment on Phone resolution

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex box which comes very nicely on the PC/Tab. But when loaded on a phone, it's getting distorted. To test this I opened the code in chrome by reducing the size of chrome window to around 1080px as thats the size of a phone. I could see the misalignment as shown in the below code pen screen shot:

[image]

The alignment even when on lower resolutions should be like below-

[image]

Any inputs are appreciated! Below is the code pen-

https://codepen.io/chandeeparora19/pen/oNxBNqL?editors=1100

```
.headlineContainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;

}

#myPhoto{
  max-width:250px;
}

#myPhoto>img{
  max-width: 100%;
}

#myHeadline{

  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0.9%; /*add - remove space*/
}

#myHeadline li{
  display: flex;
  /*border: 2px solid gray;*/
  justify-content: center;
}

#myHeadline #name{
   color: #008080;
     font-size: 340%;
     font-weight: 300;
     font-style:normal;
}

#myHeadline #Tagline{
  font-size: 150%;
    color:#000000;
}
```

Comment: add    text-align: center; to #name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add this:

```
#myHeadline {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Flex can center elements, but not the text alignment itself.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, everything is very simple. The problem is not centering, but the problem is the large `font-size: 340%` in `#myHeadline #name`. Make the value less through media queries and your problem will be solved.

Comment: I thought that the author wanted to keep this text in one line, so I suggested a solution with a reduced text size!